# How to see output in the console if the input is from web in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I am running scripts in the Webstorm. I have two files, one is index.html and another one is script.js. I am running index.html. I can input the name from the prompt window form and see the output from alert. But how can I see the output in the console?

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Script Demo</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Including JS Files</h1>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var userName = prompt("What is your name?");
alert("Nice to meet you, " + userName);
console.log("Also great to meet you, " + userName);
```

The console.log supposed to print out "Also great to meet you" + userName. But I cannot see it in the WebStorm console. How does this work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try running your code in debugger (right-click your `index.html` and choose **Debug**) - output from `console.log` will be shown in debugger console

[image]